# Spring Boot + MySQL Docker Compose: port exposure refused connection

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Spring Boot + MySQL + Docker here. I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  myappws_mono_db:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MAIN_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MAIN_DB_DATABASE
      - MYSQL_CHARSET=utf8mb4
      - MYSQL_COLLATION=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
      - MYSQL_ENGINE=InnoDB
    ports:
      - $MAIN_DB_PORT:$MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  myappws:
    depends_on:
      - myappws_mono_db
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=$SERVER_PORT
      - MAIN_DB_HOST=myappws_mono_db
      - MAIN_DB_PORT=$MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT
      - MAIN_DB_DATABASE=$MAIN_DB_DATABASE
      - MAIN_DB_USERNAME=$MAIN_DB_USERNAME
      - MAIN_DB_PASSWORD=$MAIN_DB_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - $SERVER_PORT:$WS_DOCKER_PORT
volumes:
  db:
```

The following `.env` file:

```
MAIN_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MAIN_DB_PORT=3307
MAIN_DB_DOCKER_PORT=3306
MAIN_DB_USERNAME=root
MAIN_DB_PASSWORD=123456
MAIN_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
MAIN_DB_DATABASE=myapp_db_local
SERVER_PORT=9200
WS_DOCKER_PORT=9201
```

The following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11
MAINTAINER myapp.io

RUN mkdir /opt/app

COPY app/build/libs/myapp-ws.jar myapp-ws.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","myapp-ws.jar"]
```

When I run `./gradlew clean bootJar && docker-compose --env-file .env up -d` both MySQL and Spring Boot containers start up just fine but the Spring Boot API is not available from my host machine via curl:

```
curl -ik -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"ACME, Inc.", "website":"http://example.com"}' -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:9201/ap1/v1/vendors/'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9201: Connection refused
```

When I try port 9200 (just in case) I get a similar but different error:

```
curl -ik -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"ACME, Inc.", "website":"http://example.com"}' -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/ap1/v1/vendors/'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

So clearly the Spring Boot container is not exposing its port to my host machine, but for the life of me, I'm not sure how/where to change what!?

Comment: If you do not set a specific port on your application.properties of spring-boot it will start on port 8080.. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port.
On the logs you should see something like "Tomcat started on port(s): XXXX"

Comment: I do though, the `SERVER_PORT` is set to 9200 in the `.env`, which is then fed to the docker-compose method. Docker Compose then feeds it into the `myappws` service's environment, and `application.yml` is able to pick it up.

Comment: FWIW I can do a `docker logs` and verify Tomcat (Spring Boot) is starting on 9200 (`Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9200 (http)`)

Comment: these 2 ports are not flipped? - $SERVER_PORT:$WS_DOCKER_PORT , internal port on the right and external port on the left side https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Comment: Maybe...I'd like 9200 available to the Docker host (my laptop), so should I try `- $WS_DOCKER_PORT:SERVER_PORT$` instead, @Carlos?

Comment: yes @hotmeatballsoup

Comment: That was it! If you can put this in an answer with an explanation, I'll happily give you the green check and the bounty! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the ports defined in your docker-compose file (they are flipped).

In your case 9200 is the internal port (where you are running spring-boot) and 9201 the external.

The internal port should go on the right side, and the external port (the one you want to expose) should go on the left side.

```
  ports:
  - $EXTERNAL_PORT:$INTERNAL_PORT
```

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)

Comment: Thank you, I will award you the bounty in 19 hrs once SO allows me to do so!

Answer (score 1):

The `myappws` is trying to connect to a MySQL db running inside the *same* container as the app (which is not successful since the MySQL runs in a different container).

Instead of using `127.0.0.1`, try to use the service name `myappws_mono_db` as the MySQL hostname: `MAIN_DB_HOST=myappws_mono_db` since this will resolve to the MySQL container address by docker-compose.

Comment: Thanks @Hans-Christian (+1) - so making your changes allows the Spring Boot container to connect to the MySQL container, but when both containers are running, I am not able to hit my Spring Boot container (from a curl command or the browser) at `http://localhost:9200` (I have also tried 9201 just in case). Is there something additional I need to do to expose 9200 to my host machine? Again I can use `docker logs` and see log evidence that the Spring Boot container is starting up just fine w/ full DB connections. **Thanks again for any-and-all help here!**